# How do I modify my git submodule to use a remote branch?

Tags: git

I have a remote git repository (repo A) that includes a submodule. I have branched the repository that the submodule references, and would like to update repo A.

My question is, how do I update my project so that my submodule points to my remote branch, rather than the master?

Answer (score 0):

It's two steps:

- enter the git submodule, and check out the relevant branch
- go back to the main repository and commit the change to the submodule reference

For example, step 1:

```
$ cd /some/project
$ cd vendor/foo
$ git fetch
$ git checkout origin/feature/awesome
```

step 2:

```
$ cd ..
git commit -v foo
< editor showing only the commit hash for the submodule changing >
```